# User mounted secondary drive as /var

Tags: mount, disk-usage, df

I have a drive that someone else mounted using

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /var
```

At some point they complained that all the data was missing

Now:

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /media/testdrive

df -h shows 130GB used
du -h shows 1.2MB used
```

In the `/media/testdrive` are the standard lib run spool  directories.

How should I proceed to recover the files?

Comment: `df -h` and `du -h` with what arguments? What's the filesystem?

Comment: did you run `fsck` on the file system before mounting?

Comment: I'm confused....did you do a `umount /var` before doing the second `mount` on the same partition?

Comment: @Gilles ext4, arguments as you see

Comment: @EliasTorresArroyo yes, looks clean

Comment: @mdpc  I'm confused too..  This was a drive that someone else worked on.   From the primary drive they mounted this secondary  drive with the command as shown.    It is my understanding that Linux allows this.

Comment: The files are still there since Photorec can restore them, however it would be nice to get the directory structure and file names back.